# Get a boolean vector from comparing columns using conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a matrix with column 0 and 1 that needs to be compared:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[3,4,'a'],[3,5,'b'],[9,2,'a']])
>>> df
   0  1  2
0  3  4  a
1  3  5  b
2  9  2  a
```

The goal is to compare the first and the second columns such that the we it fits a certain conditions, e.g. if we want to know whether values in column `df[0]` is lower than `df[1]`. The desired output would look as such:

```
[True, True, False]
```

I've tried to use `np.where` with a conditions but it seems like it's returning the values that fit the condition instead:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.where(df[0] < df[1], df[0], df[1])
array([3, 3, 2])
```

I could do this, but I'm sure there's a simpler way to use `numpy` or `pandas` function to get the boolean vector:

```
[row[0] < row[1] for idx, row in df.iterrows()]
```

Comment: Why not use `(df[0] < df[1]).values`? Gives you `[True, True, False]`

Comment: Actually just `df[0] < df[1]` already gives you the required result, but as as pd.Series dtype. If you want the array, you can do as @Zero suggests

Comment: 2nd/3rd argument of `np.where` returns value when true/false.  No need to use `np.where` as noted in above comments.  If you actually wanted to use it, could do `np.where(df[0] < df[1], True, False)` though that is more complicated than needed

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```
import numpy as np

df = np.array([[3,4,'a'],[3,5,'b'],[9,2,'a']])
df[0, :] == df[1, :]
#output array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
df[0, :] < df[1, :]
#output array([False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```